# Exact duplicate (closed) questions and automatic link insertion

Tags: discussion, feature-request, exact-duplicates, duplicates

The current procedure for a closed as exact duplicate automatically insert the link to the question in duplicate.

This link is denoted as "Possible Duplicate" should this say "Exact Duplicate" as the question was peer reviewed and the decision to close was reached.

Comment: That is a network wide policy, and should probably be brought up on meta.stackoverflow.com (which will become meta.stackexchange in the usual six to eight weeks). If, indeed, it has not already been brought up there.

Comment: @dmckee: if the question is properly stated and tagged I agree with the migration if they will have the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70758/ (/cc:@dmckee)

Comment: Btw, @dmckee, [posting on a child meta is fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89232/178438), though of course it is better to redirect people there for future use.

Comment: I agree with this... Was thinking such a thing myself.